# elements in an array from the sum

Tags: python, numpy

I'm new in python and I have a simple problem that I can't figure out.

I have an array let's say `A = [1 2 3 4 5]`
If we sum the elements of the array it will give 15. For instance I want the sum of the first 3 elements so I'll have 6.

My problem is I want a new array where it will give me the first 3 elements from the sum (let's call that variable my_sum). That is: `B=[1 2 3]`

I'm stuck in my code:

```
my_sum = [0]

for num in A:

    if my_sum !=6:

        my_sum = my_sum + num
```

Afterwards, I don't know what to do.

Comment: Could you please review the code formatting - indentation is important in Python.

Comment: The sum of the list is a single number, what do you mean by "elements of the sum"?

Comment: What do you mean with the first three numbers? the sum of `[1,3,5]` is the same as the sum of `[1,2,6]`...

Comment: What I mean by elements of the sum is that from A= [1 2 3 4 5], I know how to get the sum of the array which is 15. If I sum the first 3 elements of the array I get 6. What I want is after getting the sum of let's say n numbers. I want to have an array where this gives me the elements from array A that gives the sum that I want.

Comment: @justin do you mean you want to find some sub-list within the list that has a specified sum?

Comment: @justin but as CommuSoft has pointed out, there can be multiple combinations of elements from your original list that sum up to the given number.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. My problem really is to add the first few elements that give a specified sum, so I have 1+2+3 that gives me 6. Then from that, I want an array that will return [1 2 3] knowing that the sum of the first 3 elements is 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like that?!

```
import numpy

a = numpy.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
b = numpy.array([])

sum = 0
for num in a:
    if sum != 6:
       sum += num
       b = numpy.append(b, num)
    else:
       break

print b.astype(int) # [1 2 3]
```

Comment: I tried it and I got the following error: "AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'append' "

I have an array A=[1 2 3 4 5] as an input, not a list.

Comment: @justin I changed the code to work with numpy arrays.

Comment: @justin if the solution worked, it's polite to mark it as correct by clicking the checkmark below the number of votes so that other people know the problem has been solved.